# RedHat + MySQL + Tomcat: ERROR 1040: Too many connections (but everything is fine on Ubuntu)

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, redhat, hikaricp

We have an application (Java, Spring Boot, Hikari CP). Environment: Ubuntu + MySQL 5.7.25. Everything works fine.

Now we are trying to install it on RedHat (MySQL 5.7.25). The application is running. But when we are trying to log in and the application is trying to connect to DB, it is getting ERROR 1040: Too many connections. After that, we can't connect to MySQL even using the command line (it responds with ERROR 1040).

I'm not sure that increase of the number of connections will be a good solution because in the Ubuntu we are using a default value (151) and everything works fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like you may be using multiple connections within a single script. Can you show us the code for at least your login process please

Comment: /etc/security/limits.* in combination with ulimit (hard vrs soft).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. I think  I wasn't clear. Some details.

We are using the recommended Hikari configuration: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration.

As we can see from the log file, user details loaded from DB without any troubles (it is the first DB request). After that system is making next SQL-requests but getting 1040 Error.

We will check your suggestions and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the ulimit for the user mysql is running as.

The upper limit for how large you can configure max_connections in mysql is largely determined by the operating system in addition to the limit of 100,000 that MySQL sets.

Linux has a limit called max open files, this is defined “per login” and says the maximum number of files a process can open. The default is in most cases 1024, but some SELinux installs reset it to smaller numbers.

You can check it with:

```
mysql$ ulimit -n
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. We will check asap.

Comment: actually it differs from dist to dist and also from release to release, (hence the different behavior ubuntu <-> redhat )

Comment: Checked the ulimit size. It is unlimited

Comment: and here I thought this was going to be an easy answer :P . did you try logging in as admin before running the script and checking to see if connections are terminating appropriately?